# Proving a certain function is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry

I have found the following exercise on an exam for Geometry three dating to a past year.

> Let $F(u,v)=((2-v\sin\frac{u}{2})\sin u,(2-v\sin\frac{u}{2})\cos u,v\cos\frac{u}{2})$, with $F:\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3$
>
> 1. Prove $F$ is an immersion. Is it an embedding?
> 2. For $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $F_a:(a,a+2\pi)\times[-1,1]$ be the restriction of $F$. Determine whether $F_a$ is an embedding.
> 3. Let $M:=F(\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1])$. Prove $M$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The differential of this $F$ is:

[image: Differential of F]

If I take the rightmost minor, and find its zeroes, I find they make some other minor nonzero. This means that for any $(u,v)$ in the domain of $F$, this matrix has maximum rank, and thus the differential is injective, for if there are two linearly independent vectors in its image, as the rank guarantees, then the differential must be injective as it starts from $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or a subset of that). So $F$ is an immersion. It is, however, not an embedding, since it should be a homeomorphism onto its image, yet it is not injective, since shifting $u$ by $4\pi$ and keeping the same $v$ doesn't alter the value, i.e. $F(u+4k\pi,v)=F(u,v)$ for all $(u,v)$ in the domain, and what's more, shifting $u$ by $2\pi$ allows us to find the same values by changing the sign of $v$, i.e. $F(u+2\pi,-v)=F(u,v)$. So that is point 1. For point two, I convinced myself it is an embedding, but I got terribly stuck with injectivity. I tried taking two couples $(u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_2)$ and equalling their images and got stuck in a tide of terrible calculations that took me nowhere. Supposing it was injective, I supposed it was on $(a,a+2\pi]\times[-1,1]$ too, and then considered it on $[a,a+2\pi]\times[-1,1]$ quotiented with the relation that identifies $(a,v)$ with $(a+2\pi,-v)$. With the injectivity hypotheses, this becomes injective on the quotient, which is a possible realization of the Möbius band and is therefore compact, so we have an injective immersion of a compact manifold, which gives that it is an embedding. But then $F(\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1])=F(\text{Möbius band})$, so it is a regular submanifold after all.

So my problem is the injectivity of that restriction. Is there any smart way of proving it without too many calculations?

And PS Is there anything wrong with my arguments, save for lacking a proof of injectivity?

**Precisation:**
I clearly need to prove injectivity over $(a,a+2\pi]\times[-1,1]$ with the first interval semiclosed on either extreme, not with that interval open, for otherwise I need to prove $F_a$ is an embedding and point 3 is not automatic from point 2.

Is there any other appropriate tag for this? The exercise was from Differential Geometry, but the question itself is more like calculus…

Comment: It might help to note that if $F(u,v) = (x,y,z)$, then either $\cos u = 0$ or $x/y = \tan u$.

Comment: OK so if I fix $x,y$ then either $y=0$ and then $\cos u=0$ so $u=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$ which means a unique possibility with the restriction, or $\tan u=\frac xy$, meaning that to have the same value I need a new $u$ which is offset by $k\pi$, but then $\frac{u}{2}\leadsto\frac{u}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the third component becomes minus the sine, so I'd have to change $v$ and multiply it by $-\tan\frac{u}{2}$ but then the first components would change. OK, I see now.

Comment: @RolfHoyer see my answer below for a more precise and explicit rendition of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

**Comments**

OK so if I fix $x,y$ then [as Rolf Hoyer noted] either $y=0$ and then $\cos u=0$ so $u=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$ which means a unique possibility with the restriction, or $\tan u=\frac xy$, meaning that to have the same value I need a new $u$ which is offset by $k\pi$, but then $\frac{u}{2}\leadsto\frac{u}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the third component becomes minus the sine, so I'd have to change $v$ and multiply it by $-\tan\frac{u}{2}$ but then the first components would change. OK, I see now.

**First attempt, much more contorted than needed, but maybe proving something even stronger**

More explicitly, if $F(u_1,v_1)=(x,y,z)=F(u_2,v_2)$, then either $\cos u_1=0$ or $\tan u_1=\frac{x}{y}$. If $\cos u_1=0$, then either $\cos u_2=0$, which implies $u_1=u_2+k\pi$, or $\tan u_2=\frac{x}{y}$ but that is impossible since $y$ has to be 0. So if $\cos u_1=0$, $u_1=u_2+k\pi$. I got this slightly wrong in the comment because the offset is not $2k\pi$ but $k\pi$. So we have two possibilities in an interval of width $\pi$. But we have more: $u_1=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$, and $u_2=\frac{2k+1\pm2}{2}\pi$, implementing the restriction. But if I move the $u_1$ by $\pm\pi$, its half is moved by $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, meaning the third component changes, so I have to adjust $v_2$. Precisely, I would need $v_2=\frac{\pm\sin\frac{2k+1}{4}\pi}{\cos\frac{2k+1}{4}\pi}v_1=\pm\tan\frac{2k+1}{4}\pi \cdot v_1$. Actually, this will at most make $v_1=-v_2$. But let's look at the first component. We have $\sin u_1=-\sin u_2$. So we must have $2-v_1\sin\frac{u_1}{2}=v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}-2\implies v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}-v_1\sin\frac{u_1}{2}=4$. Remembering that we have $\sin\frac{u_1}{2}=\pm\sin\frac{u_2}{2}$, we get $(v_1\mp v_2)\sin\frac{u_1}{2}=4\implies v_1=\pm v_2+\frac{4}{\sin\frac{u_1}{2}}=\pm v_2-\frac{4v_1}{\frac{x}{\sin u_1}-2}$. Let's make that sine explicit: $v_1=\pm v_2\mp\frac{4v_1}{x-2}$. So $v_1=\pm v_2\cdot\frac{1}{1\pm\frac{4}{x-2}}=\pm\frac{x-2}{x-2\pm 4}v_2$. We need $|v_2|\leq1$ and $|v_1|\leq1$. The second equation gives $|x-2|\leq|x-2\pm 4|$, well, unless $x-2\pm4=0$ which means either $x=-2$ or $x=6$. Now, $|x|\leq(2+v)\cdot1=2+v$. OK, excluding those values for $x$, $|x-2|\leq|x-2\pm 4|$ if that sign is $+$ gives $|x-2|\leq|x+2|$, which is solved for $x\geq0$. So if $x<0$ I have no injectivity problems. Except maybe for $-2$. But this is getting too complex again. We are left with $\tan u_1=\frac{x}{y}$. This imposes that $\tan u_2$ be the same, since otherwise we would have $y=0$, impossible. The tangent has a period of $\pi$, so with our restriction we are left with $u_1=u_2\pm\pi$. Again, this forces $2\mp v_1\cos\frac{u_2}{2}=v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}-2$, the same as before. Btw, in the just written equation I have used that $u_1=u_2\pm\pi$ implies $\sin\frac{u_1}{2}=\pm\cos\frac{u_2}{2}$. Of course, we get $v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}\pm v_1\sin\frac{u_2}{2}=4$. And now? Maybe we can use the third component to remove some sines and cosines. From the third components, $v_1=\frac{z}{\cos\frac{u_1}{2}}=\pm\frac{z}{\sin\frac{u_2}{2}}$ and $v_2=\frac{z}{\sin\frac{u_2}{2}}$. This, of course, unless $z=0$, which gives that the above equation reduces to the blatantly false $0=4$. Substituting above, we get $z+z=4$, so $z=2$. If $z\neq 2$, we are done. Can $z$ be 2? If that is so, $v\cos\frac{u}{2}=2$. $v\neq0$, so $\cos\frac{u}{2}=\frac{2}{v}$. But $|v|\leq1$, so $|\frac{2}{v}|\geq2$, which means $z=2$ is impossible, and my proof is over. How contorted :).

**Summary, highlighting the actual proof without extra contortions**

Let me try to summarize this.

1. Use the comment to get two cases: $\cos u_1=\cos u_2=0$ and $\tan u_1=\tan u_2=\frac{x}{y}$. Mixing zero cosines with values of the tangent yields contradictions.
2. Take the first case. This gives $u_1=u_2+k\pi$, which with the restriction of $F$ in the question gives $u_1=u_2\pm\pi$. Equate first components. The sines simplify with just a sign, since shifting an angle by $\pi$ changes the signs of cosine and sine. So we get $2-\sin\frac{u_1}{2}v_1=v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}-2$. Shifting by $+\pi$ shifts the half by $+\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the sine becomes the cosine. If we shift by $-\pi$, the result on the sine of half is minus the cosine. With this the equation is $v_2\sin\frac{u_2}{2}\pm v_2\cos\frac{u_1}{2}=4$. Blatantly false, in a way I only just saw, since the modulus of the LHS is no more than 2, as the two addenda are both no greater than 1 due to the properties of the trig functions and the restriction on $v_1,v_2$.
3. Take the other case. The tangent has period $\pi$, so we get an analogous condition to before, and the same line of thought concludes.

Finally, this proof is over.