# Problem finding regular values of map

Tags: differential-geometry

I found an exercise defining $f:S^3\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ by $f(x,y,z,t)=[x+iy:z+it]$ and asking to prove it was smooth and find its regular values. Proving it was smooth was simple enough. Then I tried the critical values. I started by taking the subset $S^3\cap\{x>0\}$ and considering the chart $\phi(x,y,z,t)=(y,z,t)$, whose inverse is $\phi^{-1}(y,z,t)=(\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2-t^2},y,z,t)$, and the chart on the projective $\psi(x_0:x_1)=\frac{x_1}{x_0}$ whose inverse is, for the record, $\psi^{-1}(x)=[1:x]$. I then constructed the local representation $\overline{f}$ of $f$:

[image]

which I "decomplexified" because I have never had to do with multivariable complex functions so I prefer to stay in my domain and go from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. So I calculated its Jacobian, and I had to separate its lines and transpose them to fit it into the page margin:

[image]

I tried having Wolfram compute what seemed to be the simplest minor of this matrix, and got this piece and this piece, which had to be subtracted to one another, but when I tried that I got a Wolfram error: Wolfram|Alpha could not interpret your input. So I tried simplifying the expression with the stereographic projection as a starting chart, which at least would spare me the roots. That new chart had inverse $\phi^{-1}(a,b,c)=(\frac{-1+z^2+b^2+c^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+1},\frac{2a}{a^2+b^2+c^2+1},\frac{2b}{a^2+b^2+c^2+1},\frac{2c}{a^2+b^2+c^2+1}), at least in my imitation of [Wikipedia's 2D expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection). The new local representation I evaluated to:

[image]

and decomplexified to:

[image]

Btw, I did these Jacobians because the differential of the function is represented by them, and the critical points are where the differential is not surjective, i.e. that matrix does not have maximum rank or everywhere if the arrival space has greater dimension than the starting space. So yet another Jacobian. Actually, in this case I went straight ahead to calculating a minor, and got this piece minus the product of 1 and 2, product which wouldn't get computed. So I said: time to ask on Math SX. But before doing so, I remembered a remark done in class.

**Remark**
Let $f:X\subseteq\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$, where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $X$ is given as the counterimage $g^{-1}(a)$ of a regular value $a$ through a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ map $g:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $F$ be a function on $\Omega$ such that $F|_X=f$. Let $h=(F,g):\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}^k$. Turns out that the critical points of $f$ are those of $h$ belonging to $X$, i.e. $\mathrm{Crit}(f)=\mathrm{Crit}(h)\cap X$.

Now, I didn't remember this with this precision, so though I was not sure whether I could apply this here I tried it, and moved to considering $g(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$, so that $S^3=g^{-1}(1)$, evidently a regular value, and $h(x,y,z,t)=([x+iy:z+it],x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)$, a map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{R}$. I took the chart $\psi$ again and computed and decomplexified the local representation of $h$:

[image]

Then I evaluated its Jacobian to:

[image]

I took what seemed to be the most tractable minor and evaluated it:

[image]

Setting $y=0$, I found this would be zero if $z=0$ or $t=0$, so I found some critical points of $h$ in $S^3$, but then I tried $x=0$, and the computations were complex, so I tried the general solution, and here it is. So is there a smarter and less computation-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deserve an award for perseverance. :) In general, I have found that the best way to work with maps $f\colon M\to \Bbb P^n$ (whether $\Bbb CP^n$ or $\Bbb RP^n$, or, indeed, $S^n$) is to think of the lifted map $\tilde f\colon M\to \Bbb C^{n+1}$ or $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. (See also my answer at [Show differential of $f:S^{m}\times S^{n}\to S^{m+n+mn}$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879743/show-differential-of-fsm-times-sn-to-smnmn-is-injective/1088762#1088762).)

In your case, letting $\pi\colon\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb CP^1$, $\pi(w_1,w_2)=[w_1,w_2]$, we choose $\tilde f(x,y,z,t) = (x+iy,z+it)$, which is actually the inclusion map of $S^3$ into $\Bbb C^2$. Note that $f = \pi\circ\tilde f$, and so $df_p=d\pi_{\tilde f(p)}\circ d\tilde f_p$ fails to be surjective if and only if $\ker d\pi_{\tilde f(p)}\subset \text{im}\,d\tilde f_p = T_{\tilde f(p)}S^3$. But you should be able to see easily that at any point $w\in S^3$, $\ker d\pi_w\cap T_wS^3$ is just $1$-dimensional, the tangent line to the circle obtained by intersecting $S^3$ and the complex line spanned by $w$ in $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: I think I see. Correct me if I'm wrong. Now $\pi$ has a differential represented by $(-\frac{w_2}{w_1^2},\frac{1}{w_1})$ if $w_1\neq0$ and $(\frac{1}{w_2},-\frac{w_1}{w_2^2})$ if $w_2\neq0$, so it is always surjective, and being it a map from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$ this implies its kernel has complex dimension 1, OK that was just for the record, the if and only if part is because since we are dealing with $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps, a map into the tangent space to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is either zero or surjective… but wouldn't one then want the opposite inclusion?

Comment: I mean, if $\mathrm{d}f$ is not surjective, then, as I said above, it is 0, so it must be that $\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{d}\tilde f)\subset\ker\mathrm{d}\pi$, and if that inclusion holds, $\pi$ is surjective. Am I missing something?

Comment: As for the intersection thing, I'll think about it and come back tomorrow, but if it is true, then neither inclusion holds :).

Comment: Oh, and thx for answer and compliment :).

Comment: But what I _really_ deserve that award for is the calcs I did not copy into [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236378/proving-a-certain-function-is-injective). You have no idea :).

Comment: Be careful: The map $\Bbb C^2-\{0\}\to\Bbb CP^1$ is a map from a $2$-dimensional complex manifold (or $4$-dimensional real manifold) to a $1$-dimensional complex manifold (or $2$-dimensional real manifold), so your formula for $d\pi$ needs some care. Note that $\pi$ collapses the complex line spanned by $w$ to the point $[w]$, so the kernel of $d\pi$ is that complex line.

Comment: I thought about it again and came to this argument. The differential $\mathrm{d}\pi$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, so it is either zero or surjective. Assuming it is surjective, which I could see from my formula -- what is wrong with it? --, it means its kernel is a complex line. Again, from my formula I can see that the points it sends to zero must be orthogonal to that vector, which assuming $w_1\neq0$ gives me the points $(z,w)$ such that $-w_2z_1+w_1z_2=0$, which are precisely the complex line spanned by $(w_1,w_2)$.

Comment: With the other formula for $\mathrm{d}\pi$, I get the points orthogonal to $(w_2,-w_1)$, with exactly the same conclusion. The I thought of bringing everything into $\mathbb{R}^4$, so as to compare that complex line to the orthogonal complement of a vector, which will be the tangent space to that point on the sphere $S^3$. So if $w_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $w_2=a_2+ib_2$, $(w_1,w_2)\sim(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)$, and what is the complex line then? It must be the real span of $\{(w_1,w_2),i(w_1,w_2)\}$. Which means $\mathrm{span}\{(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2),(-b_1,a_1,b_2,a_2)\}$.

Comment: Obviously, the intersection between this and the orthogonal complement (real o.c.) of $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)$ is the real line spanned by the point $(-b_1,a_1,-b_2,a_2)\sim i(w_1,w_2)$, which means the inclusion doesn't hold. Now we look at $\mathrm{d}f$. This is a map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so for it not to be surjective its kernel has to contain at least a real plane. But $\mathrm{d}f_p=\mathrm{d}\pi_{\tilde f(p)}\circ\mathrm{d}\tilde f_p$, as you say, and the second term is injective, and the first term has a kernel that, intersected with the image of the second term, gives…

Comment: …only a real line, meaning its kernel is at most a real line, so it must be surjective. Would this work?

Comment: And what's the problem with my formula for $\mathrm{d}\pi$? I mean, the local representation of $\pi$ will be $\pi(w_1,w_2)=\frac{w_2}{w_1}$ or the reciprocal of that depending on what chart I choose, and the differential of $\pi$ should be represented by the Jacobian of the local representation, which is precisely what I gave, i.e. $(-\frac{w_2}{w_1^2},\frac{1}{w_1})$ in the first case and $(\frac{1}{w_2},-\frac{w_1}{w_2^2})$ in the other one, isn't it?

Comment: Btw, the remark I made in the question led me to finding a few critical points, but it seems there should be none, so I guess it doesn't work in this case, but why?

Comment: Sorry, I got overwhelmed with all this and didn't look carefully. Yes, in local coordinates, you're right, of course. $\pi$ is a submersion and $\ker d\pi$ is, indeed, a complex line (real $2$-dimensional subspace) which is *not* contained in $T_wS^3$, since the vector $w\in\Bbb C^2$ is not orthogonal to the complex line spanned by $w$.

Comment: So basically what I said was right, right? Good to know.